# How do I make the "successfully added to cart message" appear on any page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Ok so I have this rather confusing issue.  I am selling products using woocommerce on my wordpress site.  I have a page where I created buttons using my theme shortcodes and these buttons add products to the cart.  I have the woocommerce navigation menu and it updates when the buttons are clicked.  My issue is that no message is shown informing the client that the product has been added to the cart, no checkmark, and even the message that says "product successfully added to cart" does not appear.  However what does happen is that when I go to the checkout page, the "product successfully added" messages are all shown there.

I want the buttons on my page to be clicked, and a message that shows that the product has been added to the cart, and for the success messages not to all be shown on the checkout page.  Here's a screenshot of the issue:
www.beat-tweaks.com/uploads/woocheckout.png

Comment: You may also want to try at the [WordPress dedicated site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)